# the method doesn't add daa in the database

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean, session-bean

i'm working on an ejb 3.0 tutorial and i want to add data to the database when i set run it doesn't indicate any error and it doesn't add the following data in the db either : this is the session bean code :

```
public String creerCompte(CompteBancaire c) {

 try{
  em.persist(c);

  return null;

  }catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
GestionnaireDeCompteBancaire g=new GestionnaireDeCompteBancaire();

CompteBancaire c=new CompteBancaire("John Lennon", 150000);
g.creerCompte(c);}
```

the method main just to try the method creercompte out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't indicate any error because you catch the error it throws, return its localized message to the caller, and the caller completely ignores the returned message. Remove the `catch (Exception)` block completely, re-run your code, and you'll probably get a NullPointerException.

A session bean is not supposed to be instantiated using `new GestionnaireDeCompteBancaire()`. It's supposed to be packaged inside a Java EE application, which is deployed inside a Java EE container like JBoss or Glassfish, and then invoked using a web application deployed in this same container or using a Java EE client application. I think you really need to read a book or a serious tutorial about EJBs (and exception handling).